# Apache Shiro JdbcRealm with JavaConfig and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, shiro, spring-java-config

I'm trying to configure my Spring Boot application to use Apache Shiro as its security framework. I have everything working with a PropertiesRealm, now I'm trying to get it working with a JdbcRealm and Spring Boot's built-in H2 database. Here's my dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My schema.sql:

```
create table if not exists users (
  username varchar(256),
  password varchar(256),
  enabled boolean
);

create table if not exists user_roles (
  username varchar(256),
  role_name varchar(256)
);
```

My data.sql:

```
insert into users (username, password, enabled) values ('user', '04f8996da763b7a969b1028ee3007569eaf3a635486ddab211d512c85b9df8fb', true);

insert into user_roles (username, role_name) values ('user', 'guest');
```

And my WebSecurityConfig.java class that configures everything:

```
package security;

import org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher;
import org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.Sha256Hash;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.AnonymousFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.LogoutFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.UserFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.RolesAuthorizationFilter;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager;
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMapping = new HashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/api/health", "authc,roles[guest],ssl[8443]");
        filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/login", "authc");
        filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/logout", "logout");
        shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMapping);
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
        shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/login");
        Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
        filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());
        filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
        logoutFilter.setRedirectUrl("/login?logout");
        filters.put("logout", logoutFilter);
        filters.put("roles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
        filters.put("user", new UserFilter());
        shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);
        return shiroFilter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "securityManager")
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(jdbcRealm());
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "realm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public JdbcRealm jdbcRealm() {
        JdbcRealm realm = new JdbcRealm();
        HashedCredentialsMatcher credentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        credentialsMatcher.setHashAlgorithmName(Sha256Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
        realm.setCredentialsMatcher(credentialsMatcher);
        realm.setDataSource(dataSource);
        realm.init();
        return realm;
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WebServlet());
        registration.addUrlMappings("/console/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

I'm not seeing any errors in my logs. I tried cranking up the logging my adding the following to my application.properties, but it doesn't help much.

```
logging.level.org.apache.shiro=debug
```

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: This seems to be caused the Spring-configured dataSource not being able to be used by Apache Shiro. If I configure application.properties to talk to MySQL, it still doesn't work. If I manually create a DataSource in the JdbcRealm bean's configuration - it works.

Comment: If you need the `DataSource`  for only one bean, I 'd argue to use `@Bean` method injection as it allows the container to instantiate your `@Configuration` class without having to resolve dependencies too early. That being said, it puzzles me that it works if you create your own `DataSource`...

Comment: I have it Shiro working using the Spring-configured datasource in my application.properties and Apache Shiro. However I had to implement my own AuthorizingRealm instead of using the out-of-the-box JdbcRealm. This was not a big deal though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple problems that are happening.

## LifecycleBeanPostProcessor

The problem is due to the fact that `LifecycleBeanPostProcessor` is defined in your config class. Since it is a `BeanPostProcessor` it must be initialized eagerly to process all other beans. Furthermore, the rest of `WebSecurityConfig` needs to be initialized eagerly since it may impact `LifecycleBeanPostProcessor`.

The problem is that the autowired feature is not yet available because it is a `BeanPostProcessor` (i.e. `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`) too. This means the `DataSource` is null.

Since it is null the [`JdbcRealm` is going to throw a `NullPointerException`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/d1a3d6c88a53678504a795dc4f38568cd2dff776/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/jdbc/JdbcRealm.java#L184). This is in turn [caught by `AbstractAuthenticator`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/d1a3d6c88a53678504a795dc4f38568cd2dff776/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authc/AbstractAuthenticator.java#L214) and [rethrown as an `AuthenticationException`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/d1a3d6c88a53678504a795dc4f38568cd2dff776/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authc/AbstractAuthenticator.java#L228). The `DefaultWebSecurityManager` (actually its parent `DefaultSecurityManager`) then catches it [invokes `onFailedLogin`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/d1a3d6c88a53678504a795dc4f38568cd2dff776/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/mgt/DefaultSecurityManager.java#L272) which removes the "remember me" cookie.

### Solving LifecycleBeanPostProcessor

The easiest solution is to ensure any infrastructure related beans are defined with a static method. This informs Spring that it does not need to initialize the entire configuration class (i.e. `WebSecurityConfig`). Again

```java
@Bean
public static LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

Alternatively, you can also isolate infrastructure related beans in their own configuration.

**UPDATE**

## ShiroFilterFactoryBean

I didn't realize that `ShiroFilterFactoryBean` implements `BeanPostProcessor` also. It is pretty interesting case for an `ObjectFactory` to also implement `BeanPostProcessor`.

The problem is that this is preventing the loading of data.sql which means the application does not have any users in the table so authentication will fail.

The issue is that data.sql is loaded via a `DataSourceInitializedEvent`. However, due to the eager initialization of the `DataSource` (it was a dependency of a `BeanPostProcessor`) the `DataSourceInitializedEvent` cannot be fired. This is why you see the following in the logs:

> Could not send event to complete DataSource initialization (ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized)

### Ensuring data.sql Loads

There are a few options that I see to get the insert statements to load.

#### data.sql->schema.sql

The easiest option is to move the contents of data.sql to schema.sql. The schema.sql is still loaded since it does not require an event to be fired to process it. The data.sql requires an event so that the same mechanism can be used to load data when JPA initializes the schema.

#### Fixing the Ordering

Unfortunately, you cannot simply make the definition for `ShiroFilterFactoryBean` static since it relies on other bean definitions. Fortunately, there really is no need for the `BeanPostProcessor` in this instance. This means you can change your code to return the result of the factory bean which removes the `BeanPostProcessor` from the equation:

```
@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public AbstractShiroFilter shiroFilter() throws Exception {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMapping = new HashMap<>();
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/api/health", "authc,roles[guest],ssl[8443]");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/login", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMapping.put("/logout", "logout");
    shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMapping);
    shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
    shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/login");
    Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
    filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());
    filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
    LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
    logoutFilter.setRedirectUrl("/login?logout");
    filters.put("logout", logoutFilter);
    filters.put("roles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
    filters.put("user", new UserFilter());
    shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);
    return (AbstractShiroFilter) shiroFilter.getObject();
}
```

## insert into user

The insert statement found in data.sql is incorrect. It needs to include the `enabled` column. For example:

```
insert into users values ('admin', '22f256eca1f336a97eef2b260773cb0d81d900c208ff26e94410d292d605fed8',true);
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm able to prove the dataSource is not null when it's set on the JdbcRealm. However, authentication still doesn't work. You can see my @WebSecurityConfig at https://github.com/mraible/java-webapp-security-examples/tree/apacheshiro-h2/apache-shiro.

Comment: Here's the commit showing my working example with MySQL vs. the Spring Boot configured dataSource as you suggested: https://github.com/mraible/java-webapp-security-examples/commit/1b0fb08f35bfa3f9d9dd3bb2df283d5cbdba1fd2

Comment: @MattRaible There were two additional issues and I've updated the answer to reflect the necessary changes. I also added a PR with the necessary changes (and a few tests) https://github.com/mraible/java-webapp-security-examples/pull/1

Comment: @MattRaible Please share the code base once. I am struggling to setup