# odd things of apache-shiro integrated into spring-mvc via spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, shiro

i want to use apache-shiro to protect my URLs.
so, i did this config

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfigShiro {

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean factoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    // blah blah ...

    @Bean(name = "realm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public PropertiesRealm realm() {
        // blah blah
    }

    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor() {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor advisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        advisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
        return advisor;
    }
}
```

and here is my mvc-request-method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/html")
public class HtmlController {

    @Resource
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users");
        modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

very thing is OK. and i start my project by `mvn spring-boot:run`. and check out `http://localhost:8080/mappings`
the json result can tell me mapping `/html/users` is ready to use.
i did check out the `http://localhost:8080/html/users`, it was fine.

**BUT** once i add shiro's annotations like `@RequiresAuthentication` to my request-mapping-method like this:

```
@RequiresAuthentication    // **I ADD THIS LINE**
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users");
    modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

re-run this project, re-check `http://localhost:8080/mappings`, the mapping `/html/users` is just GONE. try to access `http://localhost:8080/html/users` i got a 404 of course.

Did i miss something? Or this is a bug of spring?

Help me please. Sorry to give you a trouble.

```
git clone git@github.com:yingzhuo/spring-playground.git
cd spring-playground
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

Comment: FYI you might want to make the lifecycleBeanPostProcessor method static as discussed http://stackoverflow.com/a/31412419/618087

Comment: Thank you. `static` make sure is lifecycleBeanPostProcessor is the first bean what to be created.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i found the answer by myslef.

```
@Bean
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator proxyCreator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        proxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true); // this SETTING
        return proxyCreator;
    }
```